# Problems with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I'm having problems working with EntityFramework. While below peace of code works fine on my PC, when it's transported to a VPS (with everything properly preinstalled), it gives me a Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object, but the message box that is supposed to catch this does not show up. Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

```
        var cc = new CopierContext();
        try
        {
            MessageBox.Show(cc.Database.Connection.ConnectionString.ToString());

            var matchingProviders2 = cc.Providers.Where(prov => prov.Login == "batman");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.InnerException.Message);
        }
```

Update:

I finally got to the core of the problem. The reason is: I've had .NET 4 on VPS, while application was developed using .NET 4.5. Installing the latter one removed all problems. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: What exactly _does_ show up? The first messagebox? Neither?

Comment: Add Trace.WriteLine(e) to your exception handler. If you can use a debugger check the output. If there is not one available where the application is deployed, then use this free tool: 
[link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: The first one shows up with no problem, second one does not. The problem is in line with "matchingProviders2", which for some reason stopped working when I placed application elsewhere (I coppied every file that was needed for it, too).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you are running it on your VPS, but if it is not launched under the interactive user account, your message boxes will not show up.

Comment: Message boxes work fine on it, but thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Well from the docs on the [Exception.InnerException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception.aspx) Property

> The InnerException property returns the same value as was passed into
>   the constructor, or **a null reference**

Since you're catching any old exception `catch (Exception e)` its quite possible that the exception that's being thrown isn't the exception you were expecting and doesn't have a InnerException. This means your catch block may be raising an exception.

There are several actions you could take.

1. Do not catch System.Exception exception in anything but a top level exception handler. Only catch exceptions you know what to do with. Which leads to...
2. Set up a top level exception handler
3. Finally when logging or displaying exception messages at least make sure you have an inner exception before you try and use it.

   `MessageBox.Show( (e.InnerException != null ? e.InnerException : e).Message );`

Comment: @ConradFrax: You're on point. You'll see stack trace and exception below.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a MessageBox as it is a service; log them to disk instead such that you can recall them, or perhaps automatically mail them to you such that you are up to date on problems occuring.

You will also want to add `e.InnerException.StackTrace` to the log.

Comment: I don't really need to log or mail them at this point. Message box works perfectly for this kind of situation as I'm trying to debug something that was working fine until it was moved on VPS.

Comment: @RobertasJ: Okay, but you still haven't provided us with a stack trace, so your message box solution clearly isn't working. Please provide more information in your question and ping me, thank you...

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that you did not configure something (or did not configure it correctly) and `cc.Database.Connection.ConnectionString` is null. Calling `.ToString()` causes the NullReferenceException. That's why you don't see the message box. As other people said - using MessageBox for this kind of debugging is not a good idea. In the catch you should print not message but e.ToString() it will show the stack trace that should point to the place where the problem is.

Comment: Even if `cc` were null this wouldn't explain why it would be an `Unhandled Exception` since that would be handled in the catch block

Comment: You said you were able to see the message box - wasn't this message box from the catch block? This question really needs more details - including stack trace since I start wondering if the exception is even thrown from the code you are showing...

Comment: @Pawel: The connection string is hardcoded at that point: @"Server=localhost;Database=CopierDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;"